# How can I show the steps of spring embedding in Mathematica?

Tags: spring, graph, wolfram-mathematica, embedding

I'm a really new user of Mathematica, and I'd need to show 9 images of a 10x10 grid graph to explain its partial transformation from a **circular** to a **spring** embedding, alligning the snapshots in a 3x3 table.

I've tried with this command:

> ```
> Grid[Partition[Table[GraphPlot[
> RandomGraph[{100, 100}, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"], 
> Method -> {"SpringEmbedding", "Rotation" -> True,
>   "RecursionMethod" -> None, MaxIterations -> i}, 
> ImageSize -> 100], {i, 9}], {3}]]
> ```

But I got 9 times the same initial circular graph, just with slightly different positions, while I'm expected to return as the 9th figure a proper grid.

Thank you in advance for every suggestion

Comment: do you get different figures if you just run `RandomGraph` alone with different maxiterations?

Comment: Maybe.. Could you show me how to do that? I'm sorry for my trivial questions, but I'm really a new user!

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me.  `9` is simply not enough iteration to see anything interesting, try `{i,1,90,10}` . Also `AspectRatio->1` after `ImageSize` makes it look better.

Comment: I thank you for your suggestion, actually something changes adding AspectRatio->1. The fact is that changing the number of iterations doesn't bring any change. I had already tried to modify it, but nothing changes, I just see two or three vertices changing positions...
I think I just go wrong in specifying that I want the number of iterations relative to the SpringEmbedding algorithm. I'm going crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

one other issue with your code is you generate a different random starting point for each figure. Fixing that, and going a few more iterations here is what I get:

```
 rg = RandomGraph[{100, 100}, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"];
 Grid[Partition[Table[GraphPlot[rg,
    Method -> {"SpringEmbedding", "Rotation" -> True, 
               "RecursionMethod" -> None,
          MaxIterations -> i},
           ImageSize -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1], {i, 36}], {6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you again for the time you spent on my problem. I must admit that even if I try to copy and paste your command lilnes, I always get the same result, that is the same graph repeated all the times I ask for. Guess there's some problem with my version. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Or, maybe, there might be problems with the version.. I've got the latest, do you have an older one? Do you think it can change something? It seems so absurd that evaluating your same lines I got a different result, just can't figure it out!

Comment: this is working with version 9.0.1. I guess you all should report the issue to wolfram support.

Answer (score 0):

```
rg = GridGraph[{10, 10}, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"];
Grid[Partition[
Table[GraphPlot[rg, 
Method -> {"SpringEmbedding", "Rotation" -> True, 
"RecursionMethod" -> None, MaxIterations -> i}, 
ImageSize -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1], {i, 16}], {4}]]
```

Also doesn't work on both 10.0.2 and 10.1!